# Laravel - How to Implement Search from Controller and View

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel-5.8 for web application. I have this model class:

```
class HrEmployee extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'hr_employees';

  protected $fillable = [
              'employee_code',
              'address',
              'company_id',
              'email',
              'employment_date',
              'first_name',
              'last_name',
              'local_government_id',
              'nationality_id',
              'other_name',
              'password',
              'phone',
              'resignation_date',
              'is_hod',
              'department_id',
          ];

protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'date_of_birth',
    'employment_date',
    'resignation_date',
];

public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\OrgCompany','company_id');
}

public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\OrgDepartment','department_id');
}

public function fullName()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->other_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}  
}
```

Controller

```
class HrEmployeesController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;

    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Super Admin')) {
        $employees = HrEmployee::paginate(6);
    } else {
        $employees = HrEmployee::where('company_id', $userCompany)->paginate(6);
    }
    return view('hr.employees.index')->with('employees', $employees);
 }
}
```

view

```
<table class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th width="10">
                #
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Employee Code </th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Employment Date</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($employees as $key => $employee)
                <td>
                    {{$key+1}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$employee->first_name}} {{$employee->last_name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$employee->email}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{isset($employee->employee_code) ? $employee->employee_code : ''}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{isset($employee->designation) ? $employee->designation->designation_name : ''}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{isset($employee->department) ? $employee->department->dept_name : ''}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$employee->employment_date ? Carbon\Carbon::parse($employee->employment_date)->format('d-m-Y') : 'N/A' }}


        </tr>
        @endforeach 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the users to be able to search by Name (first_name and last_name) - textbox, department - dropdownlist and employee_code - textbox. When the user is done, he clicks on submit button, then the result is displayed.

How do I implement this from both controller and view.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add $request var or just use $_GET on index function to get param/query of search and use where "LIKE" to filter your data

make form in your view

```
<form action="">
  <div class="input-group col-md-4">
     <input type="text" name="s" class="form-control" value="{{ $_GET['s'] ?? '' }}" placeholder="Search something...">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search!</button>
       </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

and your controller on index function

```
$s = ($_GET['s']??'');

$employees = HrEmployee::where(function($q){
    $q->where('first_name','LIKE','%'.$s.'%')->orWhere('last_name','LIKE','%'.$s.'%');
})->paginate(10)->appends($_GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to give you code that i always do,
in your blade add this code

```
{{ Form::open(['action'=> 'HrEmployeesController@search',  'method'=>'POST'])  }} 

 <label>Barcode :   {{Form::text('FirstName','',['class'=>'form-control', ])}} </label>
 {{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-sm button'])}} 
 {{Form::close()}}
```

while in your controller add search fuction

```
 public function search(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $employees = HrEmployee::where('first_name','like',"%".$request->input('FirstName')."%")->paginate(6)
          return view('hr.employees.index')->with('employees', $employees);     
    }
```

and add it to your web.php

```
Route::post('employees/Search','HrEmployeesController@search');
```

You can understand the idea i give and hope it help

Comment: How about if I want to combine first_name and last_name for a single search

Comment: are you using 2 form text or 1 form text??
it should be around like this if you use 2 form text

Comment: where('first_name','like',"%".$request->input('FirstName')."%")->where('last_name','like',"%".$request->input('LastName')."%")->paginate(20);